# Bash commands not found

Tags: bash, command-line, path

I use CentOS 7 and I install anaconda and some tools, after that  some basic command like `clear` `which` not work.

```
[zhilevan@localhost ~]$ clear
bash: clear: command not found...
```

when I `echo $PATH` I see below results

```
[zhilevan@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/home/zhilevan/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/zhilevan/.local/bin:/home/zhilevan/bin
```

Also, when I try to  `sudo yum install which` but It says already installed.

Also I try `export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/local/bin` but not correct.

**where is the problem and how can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Where is `clear` installed on your system? Does it exist in any other element of the $PATH?

Comment: @choroba tnx for your attention, it is not only  clear, some commands not work. as example  which.I echo $PATH  and you can see what I have.

Comment: But I don't see whether `which` or `clear` exist anywhere else in the $PATH.

Comment: @choroba where the clear , which and other command installed by defaults? /usr/bin ??

Comment: Try this: `hash -r`. See: `help hash`

Comment: @zhilevan: RHEL 7 default is `/usr/bin/which` and `/bin/clear`.

Comment: @Cyrus[zhilevan@localhost Downloads]$ /usr/bin/which
bash: /usr/bin/which: No such file or directory

Comment: @zhilevan what does `ls -l /usr/bin/which` return? I.e. Do you know where the executable actually is?

Comment: @forquare return `ls: cannot access /usr/bin/which: No such file or directory
` , every thing was correct until I install anaconda :(.

Comment: @zhilevan sounds like it's probably not a problem with Bash/PATH then, and something has deleted/moved key binaries.

Comment: @forquare but after it I tried `yum install which` but told `Package which-2.20-7.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`. !!!!

Comment: @zhilevan It probably is installed according to the yum database, but it sounds like the binary has been modified outside of `yum`. Try doing something like `yum reinstall which`, might have to check a -f in there somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39140/discussion-between-zhilevan-and-forquare).

Comment: Try an rpm integrity check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though some of your commands have been modified/removed outside of `yum`.

You need to reinstall the missing commands like so:

```
yum reinstall which
```

You can give multiple packages as you identify them:

```
yum reinstall which clear
```

If you find that lots of commands have been removed, it may be easier to reinstall your whole system.

Comment: I try to fix all with yum reinstall \*.
thanks for your lead and attention.

Answer (score 4):

```
yum install ncurses
```

or

```
dnf install ncurses
```

clear command should then be available

Answer (score 0):

I would try to search for the missing command by its name.

```
find / -name which
```

Assuming 'which' is the missing command, then you can add it to you PATH.

Comment: sorry my problem is not about how can I find all this tcommand one by one,I think there is a mistake than cause all this issue starts.

Comment: This is odd. It could be deleted by someone who has an access to your server.